# Barchart sizing of text & barwidth with matplotlib - python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm creating a bar chart with matplotlib-0.91 (for the first time) but the y axis labels are being cut off.  If I increase the width of the figure enough they eventually show up completely but then the output is not the correct size.

Any way to deal with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I ran into a similar problem.

See if this helps adjusting the label's font size:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.font_manager as fm

fontsize2use = 10

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
plt.xticks(fontsize=fontsize2use)  
plt.yticks(fontsize=fontsize2use)    
fontprop = fm.FontProperties(size=fontsize2use)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_xlabel('XaxisLabel')
ax.set_ylabel('YaxisLabel')
.
<main plotting code>
.
ax.legend(loc=0, prop=fontprop)
```

For the bar width, if your using [pyplot.bar](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html?#matplotlib.pyplot.bar) it looks like you can play with the width attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`subplots_adjust`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust), or just use [`axes`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.axes)`([left,bottom,width,height])`.